# Is it possible to filter out keys from an interface / type?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, key

For example, I have an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

And I only want the keys of type `string`. I managed to change the type of `id` to `never` and get all the keys from `Foo`. But `id` is still a valid key, just with type `never`.

```
const bar: keyof Partial<{ [K in keyof Foo ]: Foo [K] extends string ? Foo [K] : never }> = 'id';
```

How do I get the keys from `Foo` of type `string` only?

What I want is:

```
const bar: FooStringKeys = 'name'; // ok
const bar: FooStringKeys = 'id;    // error
```

Comment: DOes it work for you https://tsplay.dev/m3az3w ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopted from the [mapped types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  TS Playground version [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3PssACYUgCuxARtEwF9cuAPQjkAcQghowBFRr1kAByjpl0MAE9kEAB41EYdFFzaNyAMqKQdSgHkQAGy0AeACpaNAPmQBeHGYCAG0ABTUNKG0WEGQAawgtdBhkTws4SmQAUQMoI1dw9U0tABpUrxQwiOKAXV0DaVZM6lpbZAB+cosqoqitOo4IADdobxqKNIgeyO0a3AEmUXEMLAAqFvpV5EKZ4AhKMwq0TGtWun8rGztHF1cV72EEdBBqZBgTq4oV06UA7CJSBQAOQACwgTic6CBQieLzAhHQYG+n2O6B+bT+bAoACYBMgxLooGpTEtUch1lctgBpRKEEj7Q4WZFnGk6AIJJIpZn0R7PV7vNFXVlfD4s2kBABEAIgEtwsNeIER3NswtR6LorIuErYEvx4mgxKAA).

```js
interface Foo {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

// Generic string property extractor
type StringsOnly<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as Extract<Property, Type [Property] extends string ? Type [Property] : never>]: Type[Property]
};

// Foo *string* Properties
type FooString = StringsOnly<Foo>

const fooString: FooString = {name: 'hello'}
const notFooString: FooString = {id: 2} // error

// Foo *string* Key names
type FooStringKey = keyof FooString

const fooStringKey: FooStringKey = "name"
const notFooStringKey: FooStringKey = "id" // error
```